Cannot create a Date picker range in fragment layout not as a dialog
How is supposed to create a Date picker range, while the design is inside a fragment, not to click a button and show a dialog of it. Cannot find example or nothing how to do it except as dialog. I see that i can use it as Date picker, but I need it by range
I want to know if there is a way that android lets you do that
